# Logarithm and exponential inverse (base 2)

Tags: logarithms

if we have a function as follows

$$\log_2(1+ S) \leq T$$

Which of the following is correct

$$S\leq e^T-1$$ or
$$S\leq 2^T-1$$

When should each be used, i.e. with what logarithm base? 
Thanks

Comment: The second one.

Comment: When should we use the first one?

Comment: Use the first one if it was $\log_e$ or other symbol $\ln$

Answer (score 0):

If you have $\log_a(1+S)\leq T$, it means that $1+S \leq a^T$. So $S \leq a^T -1.$ Thus, this the general formula for your problem.
The first case is $a=e$, so, $S \leq e^T -1.$
The second is $a=2$, so, $S \leq 2^T -1.$